# global variable unavailable when called from dynamically created function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The global variable `selected` is called like `this.selected` and always returns the correct value.

but when called from a dynamically created function its returns `unknown`

```
onClick: function(val){
            for (i = 0; i < 
positions[this.selected].SHC.length; i++){
                var tag = 
positions[this.selected].SHC[i];
                var tagEl = 
document.createElement('p');

                console.log(this.selected) // RETURNS CORRECT VALUE
                tagEl.onclick = function(){
                    console.log(this.selected) // RETURNS UNKNOWN
                    for (j = 0; j < positions[this.selected].SHC.length; j++){

                        if (positions[this.selected].SHC[j] == this.innerHTML){
                            positions[this.selected].SHC.splice(j,1);
                        }
                    };
                ;}
                tagEl.textContent = tag;
                document.getElementById("uldshtags").appendChild(tagEl);
            }
        },
```

How can I make the global variable also available for functions created dynamically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: The second `this.selected` will have `this` set as `tagEl`, not whatever the first `this` would be.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. How do I get the global variable in this case?

Comment: Either do something like `self = this` before the new function and use `self.selected` or use `.bind` to set the value of `this` permanently for the function.

Comment: That solved it, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable and assign 'this' before 'onclick' function and use that vaiable inside 'onclick'.

```
      onClick: function (val) {
    for (i = 0; i <
        positions[this.selected].SHC.length; i++) {
        var tag =
            positions[this.selected].SHC[i];
        var tagEl =
            document.createElement('p');
        var that = this;
        console.log(this.selected) // RETURNS CORRECT VALUE
        tagEl.onclick = function () {
            console.log(that.selected) // RETURNS UNKNOWN
            for (j = 0; j < positions[that.selected].SHC.length; j++) {

                if (positions[that.selected].SHC[j] == this.innerHTML) {
                    positions[that.selected].SHC.splice(j, 1);
                }
            };

        }
        tagEl.textContent = tag;
        document.getElementById("uldshtags").appendChild(tagEl);
    }
}
```